# AndroidStudio: support package v7 seems not imported correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently upgraded to android studio 0.5.1.

Since that moment, I'm getting the following logcat message on an android 2.3.5 testing device. The messages are followed buy an instant close of the app (without a force close message). The same issue occures on an api level 8 emulator so it seems not to be devices specific.

```
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5; interface 949 'Landroid/view/View$OnLayoutChangeListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;' failed
E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.addOnLay
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 869 (Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView;
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0004-000a in Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView;.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11 ()V
```

On my Nexus 4 (Android Kitkat) the app works. 
For me, it looks like the app somehow fails to find or load the support package correctly, although it is in my build.gradle.:

```
dependencies {
    // some other imports here
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Testing with different buildToolVersions (19.0.1 and 19.0.3) and different support version (replaced the + with 19.0.+) didnt help.

Any help would be appreciated.

// Update:
I downgraded to Android Studio 0.4.2 with gradle 1.9 and it is working again. This lets me assume its a problem within AS and/or gradle 1.11. - Gonna report that as a bug

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. please update if you have any workaround other than downgrading to Android studio 0.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

changing from:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
```

to:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0'
    }
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had this before -- you have to install the support package in the android sdk [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtl40.png)

Comment: i have that installed. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Adding this section to gradle helped me out :

```
apply plugin: 'android'
...
android.aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = true
```

Also check this issue :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67412

Comment: this is my own bug report :p